# Specifying a default template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, c++17

Consider this:

```
template <typename Pack, template <typename...> class = std::tuple> struct foo;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, template <typename...> class Q>
struct foo<P<Ts...>, Q> {
    using type = Q<P<Ts>...>;   
};
```

I've placed the default template in the typedef to be `std::tuple` to make this compile, but what I actually want is the default template to be `P`, and I don't know of any syntax that allows this.  I kept the typedef simple to illustrate the point, which is trying to get `P` as the default template.  So I came up with the following workaround that seems kind of ugly:

```
template <typename Pack, template <typename...> class...> struct foo;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, template <typename...> class Q>
struct foo<P<Ts...>, Q> {
    using type = Q<P<Ts>...>;   
};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts>
struct foo<P<Ts...>> {
    using type = P<P<Ts>...>;   
};
```

Is there any better way to do it than this?  Perhaps some c++17 syntax that I'm not aware of?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What is the expected result of some given `foo<...>::type` expressions?

Comment: @ sehe  To split the pack into specific smaller packs (like the above example, but more complex), but I need to contain all the little packs, and hence the role of the default template.

Comment: How. Specifically. If you say `foo<std::tuple, int, double, std::tuple>::type` what should be the result? If that's not the correct usage, what is? What would be the result of that (assuming you magically have a working implementation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, `using` (combined with `template`) is your friend.

You need a type-traits to extract the container in `Pack`, by example

```
template <typename>
struct bar;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename ... Ts>
struct bar<P<Ts...>>
 {
   template <typename ... Us>
   using templ_type = P<Us...>;
 };
```

so you can extract the default value, for the second template parameter, from `Pack` as follows

```
template <typename Pack,
          template <typename...> class = bar<Pack>::template templ_type>
struct foo;
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename ...>
struct baz
 { };

template <typename>
struct bar;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename ... Ts>
struct bar<P<Ts...>>
 {
   template <typename ... Us>
   using templ_type = P<Us...>;
 };

template <typename Pack,
          template <typename...> class = bar<Pack>::template templ_type>
struct foo;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts,
          template <typename...> class Q>
struct foo<P<Ts...>, Q>
 { using type = Q<P<Ts>...>; };

int main()
 {
   foo<baz<short, int, long>>  f0;

   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(f0)::type,
      baz<baz<short>, baz<int>, baz<long>>>{}, "!" );
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a different default that's an identity, you can create such a thing:

```
template <class... I> struct foo_id_impl;
template <template <class...> class P, class... Ts>
struct foo_id_impl<P<Ts>...> { using type = P<P<Ts>...>; };

template <class... Id>
using foo_id = typename foo_id_impl<Id...>::type;

template <class Pack, template <class...> class = foo_id>
struct foo;
```

I'm not sure that's necessarily better than your solution, but maybe if need this in multiple places.